# Git is ignoring my android assets folder but it adds it when I commit

Tags: android, git, bitbucket, gitignore, capacitor

Im using capacitor for building my app, when I add android it comes with a folder named assets in android/app/src/main, the problem is that when I commit my app in my repo the folder isn`t included, I checked the gitignore file.

Android studio with the folder
[image: Android Studio]

Bitbucket after commit
[image: Bitbucket after commit]

My gitignore file:

```
# Specifies intentionally untracked files to ignore when using Git
# http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

*~
*.sw[mnpcod]
.tmp
*.tmp
*.tmp.*
UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
$RECYCLE.BIN/

*.log
log.txt


/.sourcemaps
/.versions
/coverage

# Ionic
/.ionic
/www
/platforms
/plugins

# Compiled output
/dist
/tmp
/out-tsc
/bazel-out

# Node
/node_modules
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log

# IDEs and editors
.idea/
.project
.classpath
.c9/
*.launch
.settings/
*.sublime-project
*.sublime-workspace

# Visual Studio Code
.vscode/*
!.vscode/settings.json
!.vscode/tasks.json
!.vscode/launch.json
!.vscode/extensions.json
.history/*


# Miscellaneous
/.angular
/.angular/cache
.sass-cache/
/connect.lock
/coverage
/libpeerconnection.log
testem.log
/typings

# System files
.DS_Store
Thumbs.db
```

Answer (score 0):

I find out that in the android app there is another gitignore file, that was the one ignoring my assets folder